# Hibernate constraint fails on cascade save

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have problem with cascade save of related entities. My UserEntity is related "one to many" with RegistrationTokenEntity. When I try to save this entities cascaded I get exception. Here is code:

UserEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "", catalog = "myDatabase")
public class UserEntity {
    private int userId;
    private String login;
    // Some other fields

    private Set<RegistrationTokenEntity> registrationTokenEntities = new HashSet<RegistrationTokenEntity>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<RegistrationTokenEntity> getRegistrationTokenEntities() {
        return registrationTokenEntities;
    }

    public void setRegistrationTokenEntities(Set<RegistrationTokenEntity> registrationTokenEntities) {
        this.registrationTokenEntities = registrationTokenEntities;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    // Some other setters and getters
}
```

RegistrationTokenEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "registration_token", schema = "", catalog = "myDatabase")
public class RegistrationTokenEntity {
    private int registrationTokenId;
    private UserEntity userId;
    // Some other fields

    @Id
    @Column(name = "registration_token_id")
    public int getRegistrationTokenId() {
        return registrationTokenId;
    }

    public void setRegistrationTokenId(int registrationTokenId) {
        this.registrationTokenId = registrationTokenId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    public UserEntity getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(UserEntity userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    // Some others setters and getters
}
```

Here is how I save:

```
private void addNewUser(SignupForm homepageForm, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity(homepageForm);

    RegistrationTokenEntity registrationTokenEntity = new RegistrationTokenEntity();
    registrationTokenEntity.setConfirmed((byte)0);
    UUID token = UUID.randomUUID();
    registrationTokenEntity.setToken(token.toString());
    registrationTokenEntity.setUserId(userEntity);
    userEntity.getRegistrationTokenEntities().add(registrationTokenEntity);

    userRepository.saveAndFlush(userEntity);
}
```

Here is my database SQL related to user and registerToken tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myDatabase`.`user` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  // Some other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `login_UNIQUE` (`login` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myDatabase`.`registration_token` (
  `registration_token_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  // Some other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`registration_token_id`, `user_id`),
  INDEX `fk_registration_token_user1_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_registration_token_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `myDatabase`.`user` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

On output I get:

```
07-Jun-2015 21:07:25.257 WARN [http-apr-8080-exec-38] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
07-Jun-2015 21:07:25.257 ERROR [http-apr-8080-exec-38] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myDatabase`.`registration_token`, CONSTRAINT `fk_registration_token_user1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
07-Jun-2015 21:07:25.260 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-38] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.release HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
07-Jun-2015 21:07:25.262 WARN [http-apr-8080-exec-38] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler.logWarning SQL Warning Code: 1452, SQLState: 23000
07-Jun-2015 21:07:25.262 WARN [http-apr-8080-exec-38] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler.logWarning Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myDatabase`.`registration_token`, CONSTRAINT `fk_registration_token_user1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

And here is root exceptions stack:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myDatabase`.`registration_token`, CONSTRAINT `fk_registration_token_user1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Have you any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you have two different DBs with "user" table: `REFERENCES appinariumweb.user`, `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myDatabase.user`?

Comment: @user3707125 no, it was my miskate on create this question. I have updated it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this!

I had to add generated value strategy to my @Id like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "registration_token_id")
public int getRegistrationTokenId() {
    return registrationTokenId;
}
```